keep getting funds in paypal but no orders convertig from it
my store front-end is on vue.js and backend on magento2,
my problem is that i am getting payments in paypal but no order information related to this payment in magento, i want to debug this issue but i am not able to find end points of magento where paypal hits or send response related to payment and then magento proceed to the order creation, i found an issue in logs
'L_SHORTMESSAGE0' => 'Total mismatch. See additional message for details.',
'L_LONGMESSAGE0' => 'The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.',
may be due to this order is not created in the magento, i only want to know where in magento it is checking the paypal response and not going to place order.
